# Storing object array with JDBCTemplate from POST method - Spring Boot

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

How to do you insert an object array into a database by using `JDBCTemplate`? I have an object array of variable length coming in from my `POST` method in my controller.

---

I have looked at these,

- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0417__Spring/PassParameterAsObjectArray.htm
- [How to insert Integer array into postgresql table using jdbcTemplate in Java Springboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303587/how-to-insert-integer-array-into-postgresql-table-using-jdbctemplate-in-java-spr)

As well as others and they do not seem to fit to what I need.

---

**Controller**

```
// Service
@Autowired
private DBService tool;

@PostMapping(value = "/foo")
private void storeData(@RequestBody CustomObject[] customObjects) {
    // Calls service then DAO
    tool.storeData(customObjects);
}
```

**POJO Object**

```
public class CustomObject {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    // Getters & Setters for class attributes
    ...
}
```

**DAO** Is this right? Because I want to store each array element separately, with each element having its own row.

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate temp;

public void storeData(CustomObject[] customObjects) {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO FooBar(name) VALUES(\'" + customObjects.toString() + "\');";

    temp.update(sql);
}
```

---

**Expected**

I want to store the array of my custom object from `POST` into my database with each element having its own row.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ideally you would want to iterate over the array and save each "CustomObject" .

```
private JdbcTemplate temp;

public void storeData(CustomObject customObject) {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO FooBar VALUES(" + customObject.id + ",\'"+  customObject.name +"\');";

    temp.update(sql);
}


@PostMapping(value = "/foo")
private void storeData(@RequestBody CustomObject[] customObjects) {
     // Save each record individually
      customObjects.forEach { customObject -> 
      tool.storeData(customObjects);
    }
}
```

Comment: neither Controller, nor DAO. Ideally you would have a service layer between the controller and dao to house that code.

Comment: JB Nizet, I agree. Oversight on my part

Comment: Concatenating values into a query string like your code is doing is extremely unsafe as it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. The proper course of actions is to use a parameterized query.

Comment: I agree, the service layer is where I will put the logic.